# Requests stuck in RequestAquireState Module Name: Session

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have an asp.net 4.0 website which runs in IIS 7.
Starting a couple of days ago, a lot of requests were stuck in RequestAquireState.

Do you have any idea where I can start look into finding a solution for my problem ?
In my code ? in IIS ? Have you ever encountered something like this ?

[image]

Comment: Having a very similar issue - I can refresh a page in our app and it will alternate between taking 2 seconds and 102 seconds, with all the time being spent in REQUEST_AQUIRE_STATE! :/

Comment: I was not treating an exception correctly. After I fixed that it didn't reproduce anymore. I don't know what exactly fixed this but now it doesn't happen again.

Comment: Thanks for the info; in our case, we don't believe any of our code has been executed before the hang, but I'll try and confirm this. I posted more details here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11250167/25124

Comment: Also, one other thing that might help is JetBrains dotTrace. An invaluable tool that will let you know exactly what line of code is taking how long (provided that you have the PDBs).

Answer (score -1):

It might be an IIS bug, see Issue 6 [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2828841).

Comment: could have been. we don't get that anymore. But seems like very probable.

Comment: The link leads to 404, able to elaborate what the bug was?

Comment: 404 page not found

Comment: I was having an exception inside a Task that was unhandled. From the request thread I was creating multiple Parallel.ForEach and one of the Tasks was failing and i was ignoring the exception.