# SignalR & Windows 7's IIS 7.5 hangs

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, signalr

I am now testing new Chat with SignalR and IIS/ASP.net 4 and friends (MySQL, etc...)

I can use SignalR with two clients (IE9, Chrome) or one only and it works. after some actions with code (refresh, change, refresh, etc...) I can see that requests to server is frozen for minutes and if I want to work I need to restart IIS.

I took a dump of IIS process, and see a ten open connections to  `poll.ashx/connect?transport=foreverFrame ....` was opened for minutes.
(I am using ashx extenstion to do not use the "runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests", as it hurting performance, it is useless)

I tried `GlobalHost.Configuration.ConnectionTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)` and  `GlobalHost.Configuration.KeepAlive = null`. same problem. I can see in the dump requests opened to 2 minutes or more.

I know that Windows 7's IIS limited to ten running  requests, so I opened Fiddler and abort all sessions.
IIS still hangs after termination.
I tried to close Fiddler (and then - TCP/HTTP connections) - still hangs.

What I can do to stop the "losted" connections? the client (Fiddler or Browser) closed the TCP/HTTP connections and in IIS there are still alive.

I do not use hubs.

Thanks !

Comment: What version of SignalR are you using?

Comment: last from source as I need a SNK signed dll.

Comment: There should be a call to abort when you refresh the browser. Are you using the latest client script as well? Generally it's bad to use IIS on windows 7 with SignalR regardless. Use iisexpress

Comment: I am using the last JS client script. I tried also manualy do `connection.stop()` on browsers, still hangs. I know that W7IIS is bad but I think that the hanged requests is a real problem. Thanks for all.

Comment: File a bug with repro steps and your sample application on github.

Comment: Update: I tried to build a repro project. I can see that SignalR ignores  `GlobalHost.Configuration.CommandTimeout` and close  connections after a long time.
I am still working on It.

Comment: @MosheL Not sure if this is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11250167/how-can-i-debug-sessionstatemodule-request-aquire-state-taking-100-seconds-on We've been having weird issues with aborted requests (cancelled by browser) hanging at IIS for 60-120 seconds and blocking all further requests (due to sessions being "locked" by requests). Happening a lot lately :-/

Comment: We're currently working around it by minimising the chances of aborted requests (eg. ajax requests in progress when a user navigates away from a page), but it feels like an IIS or .NET bug. We're only seeing it since move to IIS7.5/.NET4 :-/

Comment: @DannyTuppeny I think  that is the problem. my timeout is 20 sec, so normal (not SiganlR-ed) requests just fall after 20s. SignalR need to bybass this limit and the problem re-appair. Thanks.

Comment: @MosheL I think this is a bug (I suspect in ASP.NET 4/4.5, but can't narrow it down), however I can't find anybody else in the world reporting similar issues. We can reproduce it really easily though! :O(

Comment: I was needed to recycle app every 30-60 minutes, If I do not want to take all my system slow and down...