# Error during GENERAL_REQUEST_ENTITY for POST request causes ASP .NET session state to never get unlocked

Tags: asp.net, session, iis

(Cross posting from Server Fault where I wasn't getting any traction):
I have been trying to chase down the root cause of a condition where ASP .NET session state remains locked after a web request has been terminated due to an unexpected error. We use the SQL Server session state provider for session because we have several servers in a web farm. This issue first presented itself in the form of many requests getting stuck on the 'AcquireRequestState' event of their lifecycle for no apparent reason. I was able to finding corresponding entries for these requests in the session state database in SQL server that were all locked (column Locked = 1). I was also able to correlate these requests to entries in the IIS log with HTTP status codes of 500 (with a sub status of 0). These findings lead me to believe that, in some cases, a request was erroring out but was NOT releasing its lock on session state like it should.

I enabled Failed Request Tracing in IIS for the website in question for status code 500 with all available providers selected each with the 'Verbose' setting for verbosity. I've since gathered several failed traces that have caused permanently locked ASP .NET sessions. They all share the same characteristics:

- They are all 'POST' requests where the browser is posting data to be processed/saved.
- They all have events indicating that the 'Session' module was invoked during the REQUEST_ACQUIRE_STATE event. At this point the request would have marked the row in the session state database as being "locked". This is normal and expected.
- They all have GENERAL_READ_ENTITY_START, GENERAL_READ_ENTITY_END, and GENERAL_REQUEST_ENTITY entries that appear to be reading in the data that was posted to the server as part of the request. This appears to be a buffered operation as these events get repeated over and over with each one reading in some subset of the posted data.
- At some point during the 'read entity' related events an error occurs. Some have the error code "Incorrect function. (0x80070001)" and others have "The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request. (0x800703e3)".
- Once the error has been encountered, they all jump directly to the END_REQUEST events.

The issue here is that, under normal circumstances, there should be a RELEASE_REQUEST_STATE event that will allow the Session module to release the lock it has on the session. This event is being skipped in this scenario. Just to be sure, I enabled failed request tracing for the '200' status code as well and generated several traces of successful requests that do have the RELEASE_REQUEST_STATE event being handled by the Session module.

A co-worker pointed out that you can also cause a request to skip directly to the 'END_REQUEST' event by calling HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest(). I tested this out and saw that using this method during a post request creates a trace very similar to the ones I've been capturing when this issue has been happening, but session does still get cleaned up properly. This lead to me to running SQL Profiler on the SQL Server database where the session is stored to trace all calls to stored procedures. When we skip directly to END_REQUEST due to calling CompleteRequest(), a call is made to update the session state (and release the lock) as expected. When we skip to END_REQUEST as a result of an error during GENERAL_REQUEST_ENTITY, the call to update or release the lock on session state is never made.

My theory at this point is that some kind of network issue is causing the 'Incorrect function' and 'I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request' errors, but I don't understand why this seems to be causing the request handling to skip over the releasing the lock on session state. If the request went through REQUEST_ACQUIRE_STATE it seems like it should also release the lock at some point toward the end of the request as well. I'm loathe to say that this is a bug in IIS or ASP .NET, but it certainly appears that way to me at this point.

Are there any known conditions under which errors will lead to a session state lock not being released?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, this was related to this question: [ManagedPipelineHandler for an AJAX POST crashes if an IE9 user navigates away from a page while that call was in progress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15437524/managedpipelinehandler-for-an-ajax-post-crashes-if-an-ie9-user-navigates-away-fr)

The workaround specified in the accepted answer on that question does work, but Microsoft has also since released a hotfix (not yet publicly available as of this writing) that patches the session handling logic to avoid the issue all together.